# How to Select a Week using kendodatepicker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I an using kendodate picker in my solution.I want to retrieve the dates for full week whenever user selects some date from the kendodatepicker.e.g.lets say today is Feb 21,2014(Friday) whenever user selects some day say Feb 24,2014(Monday) then i need to retrieve its week's dates(starting and ending date).the answer should be(Feb 22,2014-Feb 28,2014)considering the fact that my week starts from Saturday(Feb 22)and ends on Friday(Feb 28).Kindly guide.i am new very much new to kendoUI.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define the `change` event handler as:

```
change : function (e) {
    // Get a reference to the row (week) containing the selected date
    var tr = $(".k-state-selected", cal._table).closest("tr");
    // Get the first day
    var first = $("td:first", tr).text();
    // Get the last day
    var last = $("td:last", tr).text());
}
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/W9VFB/9/

If you want to have the first and last date as text, then you might use:

```
var first = $("td:first", tr).find("a").attr("title");
var last = $("td:last", tr).find("a").attr("title");
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/W9VFB/12/